# Assigning responses to different tabs based on the month on timestamp

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google-sheets-query

I am collecting responses from a form and would like to separate them into different tabs based on the month of the timestamp on the response. Kinda lost on using the date/ month function in the query. Would greatly appreciate any help.

Here is a sample of my spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MSD6F-MBixbaca7Jh_2bLSMPe23GHsndPVZkz60CUHU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

OP is unregistered and does not show as having revisited since posting the above so since there seems very little chance of clarification I'm guessing that something like the following may suit:

```
=query(Sheet1!A:J,"select * where month(A)=7")
```

Here months count from `0` (for January).

[QUERY](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)